# W-функция Ламберта

Tags: функции, численные-методы

При вычислении уравнения 2x - exp(-x) = 2, получилось, что x = (1 / 2exp(x)) + 1. Потом решил проверить в Wolfram, а там решение в виде W-функции Ламберта, я немного не понимаю как мы приходим к виду x = W(1/2e) + 1 и уж тем более не понятно, как вычисляется приближённое значение 1.15718. Помогите кто-нибудь пояснить, ибо Вики с Гуглом ситуацию не прояснили.